# Moving functions to a different class C++

Tags: class, visual-c++

I agree that this is a completely newbie post, but I'm having trouble in finding out how to make a function set. I want to be able to include a set of tools, like:

```
#include <devtools.h>
```

I am unable to find a good tutorial works. I am coding in C++ for OpenCV and I would like to move my extra functions to a different class!

Comment: The problem is not that this is a newbie post but that is it not understandable. Try to show code or give examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: Do you want to move your functions into a class or just into a separate file? Please be more precise.

Comment: To elaborate, I have 50 functions in my main class. How do I move some of these functions to another file so my main class isn't 2500 lines of code long?

Comment: You simply use the Project menu command Add New Item to add a new cpp file to the project. Then cut/paste to move functions into the new file.

Comment: Wow! I never new it was so easy! Kudos to you and thanks. Let me check it out.

Answer (score 1):

'Function sets' are made in C++ using classes. A 'base' class is made and 'child' classes `extend` the base class. The child classes will have all of the same functions as the base class.

For more information about classes and extending them, read these pages on classes:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/